# Is it worthwhile rewriting the following `Dictionary` construction using Linq, and how?

Tags: c#, dictionary

For example, i don't know if it is a good practice to use Linq whenever possible.

```
     Class Aclass : Dictionary<string,int>
     {
        public Aclass(Aclass myAclass, HashSet<string> blacklist)
        {
            foreach (var item in myAclass)
            {
                if ((item.Value > 0) && (!blacklist.Contains(item.Key)))
                {
                    Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: Do you really need to inherit from `Dictionary<K,V>`? If you use composition instead of inheritance, this problem becomes much easier to solve.

Comment: I know in List case perhaps i can do this: `var mylist = aList.where(x=>(alist.value>0)&&(!blacklist.contians(alist.key))).ToList()` or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you'd be fine with:

```
Dictionary<string, int> other = ...;
HashSet<string> blacklist = ...;

var dictionary = other.Where(item => item.Value > 0 && 
                                     !blackList.Contains(item.Key)
                      .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

No need for a separate type at all as far as I can see - deriving from `Dictionary<,>` or `List<>` is almost always a bad idea IMO.

Comment: Not sure I would call the variable `query`; `ToDictionary()` doesn't defer execution, so you're just getting back a `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: @dlev: True. I originally had `dictionary` but it made the line wrap :) Will edit.

Comment: Sacrificing semantic clarity for visual clarity. *Tsk tsk*. :)

Comment: are u serious about " deriving from Dictionary<,> or List<> is almost always a bad idea "?  I didn't read of that in ur book.

Comment: @colinfang: Not everything that's a bad idea is listed in C# in Depth - although I do say at the start of chapter 10 that inheritance is overused. And yes, I'm perfectly serious. Composition is almost always a better idea IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq for this:

```
myAclass.Where(item => item.Value > 0 && !blacklist.Contains(item.Key))
        .ToList().ForEach(item => Add(item.Key, item.Value);
```

Comment: There is no built-in `ForEach` method on `IEnumerable<T>`. You can insert a `ToList()` call after the `Where()` to make things work. In fact, I did it for you :)

Comment: Better yet, just write a `ForEach` (one of the most baffling omissions from the BCL).  Creating a `List<T>` just to make LINQ work is wasteful.

Comment: @Jacob: Have you read Eric Lippert's post on ForEach? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Better yet, don't use ForEach this way. it offers almost no improvement over a foreach statement and is harder to read and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Jon. I acually did a SO search immediately after my comment and found it.  I don't agree with the decision, but it's good to know why the decision was made.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by this way:

```
public class Aclass : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>
{
    public Aclass(Aclass myAclass, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string> blacklist)
    {
        foreach (var item in myAclass)
        {
            int iCount = (from itemBlack in blacklist
                          where itemBlack == item.Key
                          select itemBlack)
                          .Count();

            if ((item.Value > 0) && (iCount == 0))
            {
                Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to turn an efficient operation (looking up a value in a `HashSet`) into an inefficient one (iterating through *all* values in the set and counting matches)?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Because Contains calls internally the Equals method, in my case Equals runs extremely slow.

Comment: You're using `==` with strings, which is going to to the same as `Equals` anyway. Honestly, this really *won't* be faster - it will be much, much slower.